# Trigger same Azure DevOps pipeline with different parameters on completion

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline that we trigger from the web interface when we want to create a release and it looks something like this:

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: release
    displayName: Release
    type: string
    default: No
    values:
      - No
      - Dev
      - Prod

trigger: none # will disable CI builds entirely

pool:
  vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"

variables:
  - template: pipelines/variables/flutter_variables.yaml
  - template: pipelines/variables/android_variables.yaml
    parameters:
      releaseMode: ${{ parameters.release }}
  - template: pipelines/variables/ios_variables.yaml
    parameters:
      releaseMode: ${{ parameters.release }

stages:
  ...
```

Upon completion of this pipeline I want to trigger another run of the the pipeline, but only if the parameter release is set to `Prod` and the second run of the pipeline should run with that parameter set to `Dev`.

Is it possible to do this with yaml, or does one have to use a script using `az` as the last step of the pipeline, and in that case what would that script look like?

Comment: Which stages do you have? also Dev and Prod?

Comment: There are lots of stages, where some run no matter what the release value is and some run only if it is Prod and some run only if it is Dev. So when the pipeline runs with Prod I want it to, after it is done, to run the pipeline again but with Dev (on the updated branch).

Comment: Why not use a multistage pipeline?

Comment: Would that really solve my problem? I want to run the same stages as in the first run again in the second run, but with different parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using az pipeline build queue command use the [az pipelines run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/pipelines?view=azure-cli-latest#az-pipelines-run), in this command you can specify the pipeline parameter

```
az pipelines run --id $(System.DefinitionId) --parameters "release=Dev"
```

The following is the working example:

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: release
    displayName: Release
    type: string
    default: No
    values:
      - No
      - Dev
      - Prod

trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
- stage: EmptyStage
  jobs:
  - job: EmptyJob
    steps:
    - script: echo "Default job"
- ${{ if eq(parameters.release, 'Prod') }}:
  - stage: TriggerDevBuild
    jobs:
      - job:
        pool:
          vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"
        steps:
          - bash: |
              az pipelines run --id $(System.DefinitionId) --parameters "release=Dev"
            displayName: 'Trigger dev build after prod build'
            env:
              AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
```

NOTE: in order for your pipeline to run another pipeline you need to assign the [queue builds permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/permissions?view=azure-devops#set-individual-pipeline-permissions) to the ADO Project Build Service user.

Verification:
Run the pipeline with the Release parameter set to Prod.
Results:
Both stages will be executed in the pipeline, after successful pipeline execution another pipeline run will be queued with the Release parameter set to Dev and only one EmptyStage will be started in the second run.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Is there a difference defining it through parameters with `az pipelines run` instead of `az pipelines build queue` where variables are defined instead?

Comment: @spydon I believe `az pipelines build queue` is used for old/classical build pipelines that do not have support for better (typed) parameters, so in your example, you can't use it, instead you need to use the `az pipelines run` IMO it is always **if possible** better to use yaml parameters rather than variables. Please accept the answer as it does what is asked in the question(_Trigger same Azure DevOps pipeline with different parameters on completion_), or let me know if there is any issue with that.

Answer (score 0):

We used the following stage as our last step to trigger the rebuild with a different parameter:

```yaml
    - ${{ if eq(parameters.release, 'Prod') }}:
      - stage: TriggerDevBuild
        condition: succeeded()
        dependsOn:
          - ...
        jobs:
          - job:
            pool:
              vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"
            steps:
              - bash: |
                  az pipelines build queue --definition-id <your pipeline definition id> --variables release=Dev
                displayName: 'Trigger dev build after prod build'
                env:
                  AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
```

It only triggers when the current pipeline is running with the release parameter set to `Prod` and when the other stages have succeeded.